# I need to display Date/Datetime field already stored on Database, based upon the <select> tag value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm not good in English sorry for that. I try to convey my problem as much as i can.

I created edit page in PHP to edit already saved data. The edit page will display already saved data's near each record there will be edit button after clicking the button model window will open to edit the saved data's., Right on that i facing some challenge.

I need to display Date/Datetime field already stored on Database, based upon the course type already selected. **(Eg: If the course type value was already selected as ==1 then automatically date field with value should display, If the value selected as ==2 then datetime field with value should display)** Hereby i attached the code.,

```
<select name="selectCourseType" id="editCourseType" required>
    <option value=""  required>Select Courses Type</option>
<?php 
    $sqlEdit = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM courses_type ORDER BY ct_id DESC");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($sqlEdit);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEdit)){
        $ctID = $row['ct_id'];
        $ctName = $row['ct_name'];
?>
    <option <?php if ($ctID==$ctType){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>  value="<?php echo $ctID ?>" ><?php echo $ctName ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
                    
                
<div id="editDeadlineDtfrom" hidden>                           
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="deadlinedatefrom" />                        
</div>

<div id="editDeadlineDtto" hidden>                           
     <input class="form-control" type="date" name="deadlinedateto" />                          
</div>

<div id="editDurationDtfrom" hidden>                          
    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="durationdatefrom" />                         
</div>

<div id="editDurationDtto" hidden>                  
    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="durationdateto" />                            
</div>


 <script>
    document.getElementById("editCourseType").addEventListener("change", function() {
        const isDeadline = this.value === "2"
        document.getElementById("editDeadlineDtfrom").hidden = !isDeadline
        document.getElementById("editDeadlineDtto").hidden = !isDeadline
    })
    document.getElementById("editCourseType").addEventListener("change", function() {
        const isDuration = this.value === "1"
        document.getElementById("editDurationDtfrom").hidden = !isDuration
        document.getElementById("editDurationDtto").hidden = !isDuration
    })

</script>
```

Comment: `hidden` is **not** a valid attribute to apply to a `div` element - use a `className` (ie: class='hidden' ) instead and put the relevant CSS rules into your stylesheet

Comment: You try to assign two `change` event handlers to the same `select` menu - why?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius actually i copy the code from create record page., i dont know how to write for edit the record

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius FIY, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden - `hidden` is valid, but might not be supported natively by all browsers. A rule in the stylesheet that applies display:none based on an attribute selector can fix that though.

Comment: Unrelated fyi, an `<option>` element doesn't take the `required` attribute

Comment: @CBroe - thanks for that, you learn something new every day!

Comment: Some body help me with some code my requirement is simple if course type value is already selected as == 1 need to display date field with value or if the value == 2 already selected datetime field with value should display

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single event handler to process the show/hide of the date,datetime elements. With a few minor alterations to the HTML ( added new classNames to certain elements to aid selection/identification and streamline code ) you could do something like this.

Use a dedicated class to hide the elements and remove that class based upon the selection made by the user.

```js
document.querySelector('select[name="selectCourseType"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const cn = 'hidden';

  //re-hide all DIV elements
  document.querySelectorAll('.ctrls').forEach(n => {
    if( !n.classList.contains(cn) ) n.classList.add(cn);
  });

  // unhide specific DIV elements based upon user selection
  switch (Number(this.value)) {
    case 1:
      document.querySelectorAll('.duration').forEach(n => n.classList.remove(cn));
    break;
    case 2:
      document.querySelectorAll('.deadline').forEach(n => n.classList.remove(cn));
    break;
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.ctrls{
  margin:0.25rem;
  padding:0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<select name="selectCourseType" required>
  <option selected hidden disabled>Select Courses Type
  <option value=1>1-Duration
  <option value=2>2-Deadline
</select>


<div class='ctrls hidden deadline'>
  <input class="form-control" type="date" name="deadlinedatefrom" />
</div>
<div class='ctrls hidden deadline'>
  <input class="form-control" type="date" name="deadlinedateto" />
</div>


<div class='ctrls hidden duration'>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="durationdatefrom" />
</div>
<div class='ctrls hidden duration'>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="durationdateto" />
</div>
```

Comment: actually i used mysql query to get the value from mysql, based upon the value from mysql database the date or datetime field should display with value

Comment: the above emulates what the select menu might contain based upon the mysql query - there is no way to accomplish the sql query and recordset iteration here - hence the statically typed example

Comment: <select name="selectCourseType"  required>
        <option value=""  selected hidden disabled>Select Courses Type</option>
         <?php 
         $sqlEdit = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM courses_type ORDER BY ct_id DESC");
         $row = mysqli_num_rows($sqlEdit);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEdit)){
          $ctID = $row['ct_id'];
          $ctName = $row['ct_name'];
         ?>
         <option <?php if ($ctID==$ctType){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>  value="<?php echo $ctID ?>" ><?php echo $ctName ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
       </select>

Comment: the above code is the mysql contains with select tag on that $ctID refers = 1/2 $ctName refers duration/deadline from that could u please help me how to pass the value to js

Comment: could u please help me with the code to understand i tried all the way but not working

Comment: can you look at the source code of the HTML and copy/paste the rendered HTML... WHat I put above **should** be sufficient for you to get the show/hide working but if you add the rendered HTML I will know more

Comment: I tried it but now working for me